# what is my increment percentage from 0 to 20?

Tags: percentage, cost-management

Suppose, I have a pen, which initially cost 0 $, now it costs 20$.
What is the increment percentage?

Ideally, it will cause the divide by zero exception.

Comment: This should be on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

There are things which happen practically first and they are made part of study. Then, there are things which are believed, experimented with, and set in theory and later proven practically. Mathematics deals with both of them. This is a mathematical question, not astronomical. This is not a planetary distance calculation whose actual value is unknown and even current value is unknown.  It's not like part of unknown is unknown, but which part, nobody knows.

A pen does exist. It is not virtual. It costs nothing. Why? May have been free with something, but it does have an actual price which is not known. So, there is a definite price increase from 0 $ to 20 $. That means, 20 - 0 is the increase.

You cannot divide ultimately by 0 because you cannot divide 20 into any number of fragments of 0. So, 0 raise to power n will always remain 0 and never reach 20.

Infinity hence cannot be the answer as well since 0^infinity is zero. That is why, in such cases, you can accept the numerator and denominator can be set to 1, to replace the unknown actual price of the pen.

Dividing by zero is infinity, so in such questions which need definitive calculation and not infinity answer, 0 is changed to 1 for division, not for subtraction, to let the numerator decide the increase factor. Infinity is convenience here, not the answer. The earlier actual price of the pen is indeterminate, so you cannot divide by it.

So, denominator can be treated as Case number WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE number. So, it will be ((20-0) * 100)/1 = 2000%. So, price has raised by 2000% for the end consumer of the pen.

Answer (score 0):

How You find increment percentage if its initial cost is zero? it should be greater than zero

For example

initial cost 10
New cost 20

then

```
(20-10)/10 *100
```

So

100 % is increment %

Answer (score -1):

The increment percentage is undefined because you can't divide by zero.

The formula is `(new-old)/old` and this turns into `20/0`